# how to upload files from different subfolders into different subfolders with Django

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models

I have many files under a folder(for example, 'datasets') and these files are separated in many different sub–dictionaries.

I want to let user specify the folder 'datasets' in a form and upload all the files in Django. After upload, The Django view function will extract some pieces  information from each files and save into database. how can I do this.

The following is the structure of my files to be uploaded:

```
datasets
- subfolder 1
   -  file1
   -  file2
   -  subfolder 1a
       - file3
- subfolder 2
   -  file4
- file5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FileField.upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) is defined as follows

> This attribute provides a way of setting the upload directory and file
>   name, and can be set in two ways. In both cases, the value is passed
>   to the Storage.save() method. ... upload_to may also be a callable,
>   such as a function. This will be called to obtain the upload path,
>   including the filename. This callable must accept two arguments and
>   return a Unix-style path (with forward slashes) to be passed along to
>   the storage system. The two arguments are:

So what you need to do is to create a function that will check the filename or it's content and decide where the file should be saved

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    if filename .... :
        return 'path1'
    else :
        return 'path2'
```

And your model will change to

```
image = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

Comment: nice editing. You answer solve myproblem of saving files into different subfolders. But what if I want to upload files from different subfolders. I read documentation. The default upload only let you upload multiple files from one folder. If there are files in subfolders under that folder, files in subfolders will be ignored. I have editing my question title to clarify my question.

Comment: That's not a django issue. That's browser behaviour. You will have to use a recursive file uploader in the client side. I am not sure if there are any at the moment most of the ones that existed were made with java.

Comment: so how did this go?

Comment: I have find a tricky solution by zip all the subdictionaries and files. Then use zipfile module and your code to handle the rest part

Comment: yes, now days that  seems the only option. I also used to have a recursive file uploader applet but that doesn't work anymore because browsers notably chrome dropping support.